# Application of a marginal rate at the breakpoint

Tags: limits

I'm not a mathematician, so please forgive my imprecision.

A colleague and I are having an argument. I'd love some help settling it.

Assume two tax rates: $Y = 5\%$, and $Z = 10\%$; which are charged on income $X$.

For all $X < 100$, your taxes = $X\times Y$. For all $X > 100$, your taxes (on the portion over 100) = $X\times Z$

Is that different from / does it make sense to say:

For all $X < 100$, then $X\times Y$. For all X $\geq$ 100, then $X\times Z$.
(The idea being that you're taxed at $5\%$ up to $99.999...$, but that "at" $100$, you're taxed $10\%$)

The argument is whether the "equal to" makes sense. I argue that there's no income "at" $100$ to tax. It's just a breakpoint, and as such there can be no measurement of income to which to apply the tax rate. My friend argues that you're somehow capturing something there. I've tried drawing a graph and explaining that you'd basically be asking someone to capture the area under a vertical line, but that's about as math-y as I can get.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Here's another way to think about it (and again, sorry for the imprecision of my thought process): let's say I want to calculate the area on a simple chart. 

Assume Y = 10. I want to know the value under the "curve" bounded by Y for X = 1 through X = 5. 

The "width" of X is 4, times the "height" of Y at 10 gives me 40.

Now, does it change anything (or make sense in the first place) if I ask for the area bounded by Y for X greater than (but not equal to) 1, through X = 5?

Answer (score 0):

I guess we would need to ask the question of how much tax do I need to pay if someone gave me \$100 exactly. How we handle this case will determine how much tax we pay.

I would say that certainly someone can earn exactly \$100 income, so we need to have a case for when someone earns exactly \$100.

We need to handle X=100, as that legitimately could occur.

So unfortunately, it seems that the friend may be correct.

Comment: But it's only the application of a marginal rate. For the first 99.999..., the rate will always be 5%. The question is whether you capture more by saying "equal to", such that the value "at" 100 is taxed at 10%.